# Need batch file to pull Quicken data file from network location, and then put back when done

Tags: batch-file, quicken

My husband and I use Quicken on two separate computers on the same home network.  We have two installations of the application, but only one data file that resides on my husband's machine.

Quicken doesn't work well when I try to open the data file across the network from my machine.  It runs very slow and has unexplainable errors.

So, instead, I need a batch file to copy the data file to my machine so I can use it, then put it back when I'm done.

Any suggestions where to start?

Comment: Hi Gabby, questions that are not programming specific are better asked on SuperUser.com

Comment: Oh sorry.  I guess I always thought of batch-files as real programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do something very similar.

```
REM Networked Drive isnt always recognized from DOS unless its mapped in explorer first
explorer /n,q:\
call wait 5
copy "q:\Quicken.QDF" C:\
REM Backup the Quicken copy from your Q drive
move "q:\Quicken.QDF" "Q:\QuickenBackup%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%%date:~10,4%.QDF"
REM Now run Quicken
"C:\Quicken.QDF"
REM After youre done with the data file, put it back
copy "C:\Quicken.QDF" Q:\Temp.QDF
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 GOTO NOPROBLEM

ECHO    A Problem with "COPY" Has Occurred 
ECHO     Please Correct It and Try Again
GOTO END

:NOPROBLEM
move Q:\Temp.QDF "q:\Quicken.QDF"
move "C:\Quicken.QDF" "C:\QuickenBackup%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%%date:~10,4%.QDF"


:END

pause
```

Comment: Nice touch on doing automated back-ups.  But what is the WAIT command in line 3?  I don't seem to have that in my system.  (Windows XP, SP2)

Comment: wait.bat is another batch file with the following lines: 
@ping 127.0.0.1 -n 2 -w 1000 > nul
@ping 127.0.0.1 -n %1% -w 1000> nul

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be what I was looking for.  How can I check to make sure that my husband isn't using the file at the same time I try to 'get' it?